# Populating dojo ComboBox with JSON

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo

This is my code:

```
dojo.xhrGet({

    url: "/api/products",
    load: function (result) {

        require([
    "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function (Memory, ComboBox) {

            console.log(result); // this outputs the data successfully...

            var stateStore = new Memory({
                data: result // but, this says it's "undefined"
            });

            var comboBox = new ComboBox({
                id: "stateSelect",
                store: stateStore,
                searchAttr: "Name"
            }, "stateSelect");
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see from my comments above, the data is output properly in my `console.log()`, but when I try to use it in `new Memory()` it says it's "undefined."  How can I properly fill my ComboBox with JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you have mentioned its json data, you should also include handleAs: "json" in your code.

```
dojo.xhrGet({

   url: "/api/products",
   handleAs: "json", ///
   load: function (result) {
   .....
   .....
   }
});
```